# get quantity value from Shopify datalayer

Tags: shopify, google-tag-manager

I need to extract the quantity (number of products that were purchased) from Shopify, to use it in my Google Tag Manager. I don't know if I can extract this value from Shopify.Checkout datalayer or need to get this value from somewhere.

Can anyone help me? I see in Shopify doc that the Quantity parameter is in line_items object (https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/checkout#resource_object)

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path.
You need to extract the quantity from the line items, you can probably use something like:

```
{%- for item in checkout.line_items -%}
  var quantity = {{- item.quantity | json -}};
{%- endfor -%}
```